# Accessing data from a function INSIDE a class

Tags: python-3.x

I have a class, a function INSIDE the class, and I want to print out from inside the function. The function is changing X.

I have tried to print out like so.

```
class apples:
    quantity = 0
    def howMuch(self,x):
        quantity = x #because i am going to set it
fruit = apples()
fruit.howMuch(10)
print(fruit.quantity)
```

Output: 0

I was expecting it to print out the NEW amount I assigned it, instead it didn't modified and it kept the "original" value.

Edit: I want to use like so

```
ate = fruit.howMuch.quantity - 1
```

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Please [reformat your code](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) using the linked guide.

Answer (score 0):

You stored the quantity in a local variable and a class variable, and when you check, you check the instance attribute, falling back to the class variable. What you want instead is to just go for instance attributes:

```
class apples:
    def __init__(self):  # gets executed when you instantiate a new apples object
        self.quantity = 0
    def howMuch(self,x):
        self.quantity = x #because i am going to set it

fruit = apples()
fruit.howMuch(10)
print(fruit.quantity)
```

I think you might have the whole terminology backwards though — wouldn't you want a class called `Fruits` and have an instance called `apples`?

Regarding your edit, what you want is *possible*, but very likely misguided. With this solution, however, you are able to do `ate = fruit.quantity - 1`